# Format cell data type when data added with worksheet.add_table

Tags: xlsxwriter

First, love xlsxwriter. Use both python and perl modules. Thanks so much to John M.

When creating a table using add_table(), all the data cells get data formatted as text. Even if only integers in the data. An integer view as text causes a small green triangle to appear in the upper left of each cell viewed in Excel.

Is there anyway to go back and modify cell data types after adding data with add_table??

Here is the tidbit of code doing the add_table() :

```
    worksheet = self.add_worksheet(name)
    worksheet.header = header
    tableinfo= {
        'data' : data,
        'columns' : columns
        }
    lastcol = scol + (len(header) - 1)
    lastrow = srow + len(data)
    worksheet.add_table(srow,scol,lastrow,lastcol,tableinfo)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When creating a table using add_table(), all the data cells get data formatted as text. Even if only integers in the data.

That shouldn't be the case. The `add_table()` method uses the `write()` method which writes the correct Excel data type based on the Python data type.

You can see that it works as expected using the [table example in the docs](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_tables.html).

So, if you are seeing green warning triangle it is probably because you have numeric data stores as strings in your Python code.

If you convert your sample code to a working example we could verify that.

Comment: John, you are right of course. Looked at the type() for the list of list elements and they are all str. Think I need to create a function to walk my list of lists and change from str to int where int detected.   Much thanks! Keep up the great work on xlsxwriter.